# How to avoid hitting App Engines free limits with tons of writes?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to handle remote logging with app engine, but I find just by myself I'm exceeding the daily write limit. Are there any datastore tricks I can use to consume less of my write quota while posting data to the server constantly?

Comment: Don't write if it's small data in the log your are serving you could just write to the log service and then later process there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pack more data into an entity, and arrange to not index any fields you're never going to query on. That may interfere with querying your logs, but if writes predominate, pack more into each write, saving writes and index updates. You'll pay for it later when querying, but if queries are infrequent, it may be a net win.

Comment: How would I pack more into each write? Like, if I receive one post one second, and a second post the next second, how can I combine the writes? I suppose memcache is a possibility, but then I'd be concerned about data loss.

Comment: If you can afford to lose the occasional log message, caching a few in an instance before writing a bunch is one approach. Caching in memcache is another. But if you can't afford to drop any log messages, then yeah, you've got a problem staying within free quota when you're load increases.